# Symbology showing dyadic relationships between polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, relates

I have an interesting styling challenge which I don't know how to begin to solve. I have polygons which have qualitative (string) dyadic relationships with each other, and I need to make a series of maps which graphically show the relationships of each polygon.

The best analogy I can come up with is one of those diplomatic relations maps or maybe sports teams - polygon A has an 'alliance' w polygon B, a 'treaty' w polygons C and D, and 'war' w polygon E. Each of these categories would then have a different color for the map featuring Polygon A. I would need five of these, one for each polygon.

How can I define these dyadic relationships and make it so I can quickly generate a series of maps like this?

---

To give you all a more clear example, I have a series of polygons which have their own attribute tables. In addition, they have dyadic relationships which for the sake of analogy might look like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |  |
| B | friend |  |  |  |
| C | peace | peace |  |  |
| D | war | war | friend |  |

For the 'A' map, I would want A to be black, B to be green, C to be blue, and D to be red. For the 'C' map, C would be black, while A, B, and C would all be blue. For 'D', A and B would be red while C would be green.

I need to do this with ~a hundred polygons, so creating a column in the attribute table for every other polygon to do this 'directly' is impractical.